# load JSONP with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I try to load a JSONP File with AngularJS.
This is my code:

```
var urlCal = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/nmk97b3l07ncb9f9h5ap5ffo2c@group.calendar.google.com/public/full';
var allParams = {
    "alt" : "json-in-script",
    "orderby" : "starttime",
    "max-results" : "15",
    "singleevents" : "true",
    "sortorder" : "ascending",
    "futureevents" : "true" 
}
$http.jsonp(urlCal + "?callback=bla", {params: allParams})
.success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

but when I run this in the brouwser it sows me this error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: bla is not defined "

I think the problem is that the json file starts with "// API callback" but I am not sure.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: try using `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Per Angular's `$http.jsonp` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp), you need to use `JSON_CALLBACK` rather than a named callback:

```
"?callback=JSON_CALLBACK"
```

Angular will create the callback function name automatically.  Otherwise you would have to define `bla`.

Comment: The documentation is very unclear. I've to read angular source code to confirm the behavior :(